# Laravel 5.3 passing data to password reset template failing

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-5

I am trying to pass a pageTitle variable to the password reset template (/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php) in Laravel 5.3 in the following way:

```
return view('auth.passwords.reset')
    ->with('pageTitle', 'Change title')
    ->with(['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]);
```

this goes in the `showResetForm` method inside `ResetsPasswords` trait - and it doesn't work. Google doesn't come up with any helpful results. I've tried removing the line:

```
    ->with(['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]);
```

but it still doesn't work. I've also tried

```
$pageTitle = 'Change me';
return view('auth.passwords.reset', compact('pageTitle'));
```

but it doesn't work. Also, I've realized that the `ResetsPassword` trait is found in the vendor folder so it's a bad idea to change the code there, how do you suggest I do this instead? Can I overwrite the `showResetForm` method somewhere? - I found that for the registration trait I can put the `showRegistrationForm` in the `RegistrationController` and pass whatever variables I want to the view there; however that doesn't work for the `ResetPasswordController`

EDIT:

Here is the whole method from the `ResetsPasswords` trait, as requested:

```
/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was editing the wrong trait, I need to edit the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait and not the `ResetsPassword`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `compact`

```
return view('auth.passwords.reset', compact('token', 'email', etc..));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('auth.passwords.reset')
    ->with(['pageTitle' => 'Change Title','token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]);
```

have you tried it like this?

**EDIT**

```
$pageTitle = 'Change Title';
$token = 'token';
$email = 'email';
return view('auth.passwords.reset', compact('pageTitle','token','email'));
```

Comment: in that case use compact. i'll edit the question in a sec